# while I am running c program the three loops are not terminating?

Tags: c

When I execute this program, it does not terminate.

For instance, if I give it the input `A`, the output will be:

```
65 
7
1000001
0
65
7
1000001
...
```

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void main()
{
    int BinaryArray[10], Counter = 0, CounterTwo = 0, length, Ascii = 0;
    char inputstring[100];
    printf("Enter the string: ");
    scanf("%s", inputstring);
    // Ascii = 'B';
    // printf("%d\n", Ascii);
    // printf("%d\n", inputstring[0]);
    // printf("The Ascii value of %c is %d", 'A', 'A');
    length = strlen(inputstring);
    // printf("%d\n", length);

    for (Counter = 0; Counter < length; Counter++)
    {
        Ascii = inputstring[Counter];
        printf("%d\n", Ascii);
        for(Counter = 0; Ascii > 0; Counter++)
        {
            BinaryArray[Counter] = Ascii % 2;
            Ascii = Ascii / 2;
        }
        printf("%d\n", Counter);
        for (Counter = Counter - 1; Counter >= 0; Counter--)
        {
            printf("%d", BinaryArray[Counter]);
        }
        printf("\n");
        Ascii = 0;
        printf("%d\n", Ascii);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because after this loop

```
for (Counter = Counter - 1; Counter >= 0; Counter--)
    {
        printf("%d", BinaryArray[Counter]);
    }
```

Counter will be set to 0. To fix store is value in a var, and  use it in the for loop instead of using the Counter var.

Answer (score 0):

You have a loop in the loop using the same global control variable. What to do:

1. Use another variables for particular loop
2. Use local variables in the for loops.